# HTML/CSS: how to achieve this cross-like page layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

What would be the best way to achieve the following HTML page layout?

```
+----------------+-----------+----------------+
| space-TL       | content-T |       space-TR |
+----------+-----+-----------+-----+----------+
| space-CL |       content-C       | space-CR |
+----------+-----+-----------+-----+----------+
| space-BL       | content-B |       space-BR |
+----------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Here, the 4 `space-*` boxes in the corners (`space-T*` and `space-B*`) must be of **equal width**, whereas `content-C` must be horizontally centered but can be wider than either `content-T` or `content-B`. All 3 `content-*` boxes are of variable width, depending on their content.

- I tried setting a combination of horizontal `margin: auto` and `max-width` on all 3 `content-*` boxes, which seems to work pretty fine. But if, say, `content-T` is too narrow then nothing will prevent `space-TL` from becoming wider than `space-BL`.
- I am considering `display: grid` on the outer container, but it looks like an overkill to me because I'd need to provide explicit boxes for each of the 6 `space-*` elements.
- So maybe I will do a 3-column layout instead, and then just allow `content-C` to stretch outside the mid-column with `overflow: visible`?

What would be your approach?

Heights of the boxes are not so relevant and can be content-dependent.

Thanks!

Comment: Fairly sure equalising the widths of the out columns is not possible with CSS. You need javascript.

Comment: I can’t quite make sense of the description. What determines the width of those corner cells?

Answer (score 0):

Information that would have been useful to have is whether the corners will have a known fixed width and if the content of the center block will be  images or wrapping text. Based on the limited information given, I came up with this solution using three rows of flexbox.

The first and third columns have a [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) and [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) of 0 with a [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) of 200px `flex: 0 0 200px`.

In the middle row, these outer columns are given `flex-shrink: .5` and the center column is given `flex-grow: 1`. All of the outer columns will be 200px wide unless the center content needs more room and shrinks the adjacent columns.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: .5em;
  }

.row div {
  margin-block: .25em;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid;
  }

.row div:nth-of-type(1),
.row div:nth-of-type(3) {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  }

.middle div:nth-of-type(1),
.middle div:nth-of-type(3) {
  flex-shrink: .5;
  }

.middle div:nth-of-type(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  }

figure {
  width: 500px;
  aspect-ratio: 2;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>space-TL Here, the 4 space-* boxes in the corners (space-T* and space-B*) must be of equal width, whereas content-C must be horizontally centered but can be wider than either content-T or content-B. All 3 content-* boxes are of variable width, depending on their content.</div>
  <div>content-T Here, the 4 space-* boxes in the corners (space-T* and space-B*) must be of equal width, whereas content-C must be horizontally centered but can be wider than either content-T or content-B. All 3 content-* boxes are of variable width, depending on their content.</div>
  <div>space-TR Here, the 4 space-* boxes in the corners (space-T* and space-B*) must be of equal width, whereas content-C must be horizontally centered but can be wider than either content-T or content-B. All 3 content-* boxes are of variable width, depending on their content.</div>
</div>
<div class="middle row">
  <div>space-CL Here, the 4 space-* boxes in the corners (space-T* and space-B*) must be of equal width, whereas content-C must be horizontally centered but can be wider than either content-T or content-B. All 3 content-* boxes are of variable width, depending on their content.</div>
  <div>content-C<figure></figure></div>
  <div>space-CR Here, the 4 space-* boxes in the corners (space-T* and space-B*) must be of equal width, whereas content-C must be horizontally centered but can be wider than either content-T or content-B. All 3 content-* boxes are of variable width, depending on their content.</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>space-BL Here, the 4 space-* boxes in the corners (space-T* and space-B*) must be of equal width, whereas content-C must be horizontally centered but can be wider than either content-T or content-B. All 3 content-* boxes are of variable width, depending on their content.</div>
  <div>content-B Here, the 4 space-* boxes in the corners (space-T* and space-B*) must be of equal width, whereas content-C must be horizontally centered but can be wider than either content-T or content-B. All 3 content-* boxes are of variable width, depending on their content.</div>
  <div>space-BR Here, the 4 space-* boxes in the corners (space-T* and space-B*) must be of equal width, whereas content-C must be horizontally centered but can be wider than either content-T or content-B. All 3 content-* boxes are of variable width, depending on their content.</div>
</div>
```